# Aws glue triggers are not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have tried to run AWS glue trigger with proper values but it is not going to run job, On which we have setup the trigger.

For instance I have Job1 and Job2. On complition of Job1 i want to run Job2. Job1 is getting passed but it is unable to trigger Job2.

Can you please help me to know what am i missing?

Comment: Hi Pavan were you able to get this resolved ? I am having the same issue

Comment: No, We moved to oozie

Comment: We had a exclusive call with the Glue Team and this feature is not supported yet, on thing works thought (if this can be done on ur project) if all the dependent job runs under one trigger then the following "On job Completion) trigger kick starts fine

Answer (score 15):

Old ticket but my problem was the trigger was not "enabled". In the AWS console select the trigger, and in actions click enable. At the time of writing this was not possible to do via cloudformation :(

Comment: There is (now) a `StartOnCreation` parameter which can be set to `true` in the CF.

Comment: Thanks, old but still a life-saver!

Answer (score 7):

From AWS documentation:

> Dependent jobs are only started if the job which completes was started by a trigger (not run ad-hoc). All jobs in a dependency chain must be descendants of a single schedule or on-demand trigger.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/trigger-job.html

Comment: I had a similar problem where I had a workflow of DAG of jobs connected via triggers. The first job was supposed to be run via a scheduled trigger and the rest of the jobs were chained and to be run via triggers on completion of the previous job. This workflow would only work when the scheduled trigger would execute and not when I would try and run the first job on demand.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another on-demand job and trigger your job by the new job. That would work.